# Do disassemblers detect standard functions?

Tags: header-files, standard-library, disassembly

Do disassemblers detect the use of C/C++ standard functions and specify them in the output code, adding the `#include` line to the appropriate header file (such as `stdio.h` or even `windows.h`)?

If not, does the whole big library is being recognized as the developer's own business-logic code, and written fully? Aren't the standard libraries known binary sequences (or can be processed some way to be known, as a binary-code can be different because of addressing)?

Do you know disassemblers that do detect standard functions and properly #include them in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDA can do it for a number of compilers' standard libraries and you can program your own recognizers as FLIRT modules. It's not free though.

Comment: An old version (5.0) can be downloaded for free: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml